# How to deal with multiple Google Maps markers on the exact same position

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What I'm trying to do is finding an elegant way of dealing with multiple markers on **the exact same spot** on a google map. Possible scenarios are when your geo data just isn't accurate enough to distinguish two markers from one another (say 3 people live in the same house and all you have is an address) or you only have city information of a couple of shops.

Now there is the Clusterer of course, everybody is saying that, but that won't help here as the markers have the exact same location. They will stay clustered regardless of zoom level.

I like the way Google Earth does it. [Here is an example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/263/testeo.png/). But so far I have not discovered a way to have this behavior in Google Maps. I would be pleased if someone can show me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So perhaps as you are looping through your coordinates adding all the markers, you could check if any previous marker has the same latlng. If it has you could use a different marker, e.g one numbered '2'.  Or to do the Google Earth thing, offset each marker slightly, and draw a polyline from the markers to the original location.

Comment: Yes after I discovered how easy it is to draw lines on the map I think that will be the better option too. It's not all that hard, just have the proper event handlers on the top marker. Also: in the same app I would like to use the Clusterer still, as I'm also dealing with possibly a lot of markers. Is that possible to manipulate individual markers once you send them to the Cluster Manager?

Comment: Yes I think so... one thing I've noticed is that if you make the markers draggable, the cluster will automatically update as you drag markers around, e.g. adding them into a nearby cluster